# Get value from php json array

Tags: php, json

Nothing seems to work to get the last price from this ticker

```
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-ghc';
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode ($execResult,true);
```

I've tried

```
$price = $json['result'][0]['Last'];
$price = $json->result[0]->Last;
```

and a variety of other options.. php fiddle doesn't offer a link

```
var_dump($json);
```

returns

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"MarketName":"BTC-GHC","High":0.00000474,"Low":0.00000429,"Volume":345725.27775903,"Last":0.00000468,"BaseVolume":1.62834409,"TimeStamp":"2015-09-04T13:28:21.513","Bid":0.00000432,"Ask":0.00000467,"OpenBuyOrders":25,"OpenSellOrders":112,"PrevDay":0.00000429,"Created":"2014-10-09T01:05:23.733"}]}
```

Comment: try: `var_dump($json);` to see what it looks like.

Comment: Add this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); `

Comment: adding that returns 4.68E-6 as the last price...

Comment: no, unless I'm suppose to convert that to show 0.00000468 which is the real last price

Comment: This is the same number in scientific notation. You can convert this by `echo number_format($no, 8);`

Comment: works... life server... make that an answer so I can give you credit please

Comment: I'm so glad that I could help!

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `curl_exec` to return the data, you have to set an option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Also if you do not want number to be displayed in scientific notation, you can convert it using this function:

```
$price = number_format($price, 8);
```